# appending new dataframe to empty dataframe in pandas gives extra header

Tags: python, pandas

I have created an empty dataframe with custom header like below

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Background','Skin','Eyes','Eye Accessory','Facial Hair','Body','Ear Accessory','Head','Mouth'])
```

and when appending new dataframe the data is like below

```
         0    1        2      3       4            5          6        7          8
value   Red Pink    Holes   None    Beard   Hoodie Blue    Standard   Bald    Cigarette
```

using this code

```
df2 = df2.append(df_t)
df2
```

i get the below result with the custom header moved aside to extra column like below

[image: extra column]

how can i make the custom header the header of new dataframe that is appended without going to extra column.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example

Comment: @Luke i want to make it look like this https://imgur.com/a/aiz5M3M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need same columns values in both DataFrames:

```
df_t.columns = df2.columns
df2 = df2.append(df_t)
```